# Magento2 - Add modernizr class to <html>

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, template, frontend

i want to add `class="no-js"` to the `<html>` Element. 
How can i do this?

Is this possible with XML or should i override `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml` ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.0 have working  tag what can be included between body and head. I added it:

> THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Example:

```
<page ... >
  <html>
    <attribute name="class" value="no-js"/>
  </html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>...</body>
</page>
```

In Magento 2.2 is broken. 
Created new issue for this:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11697